# CONFIG/Lite and Arrays

Tags: php, pear

Just gotten started with Config/Lite (https://github.com/pear/Config_Lite)

But it seems that it doesnt like array variables, for instance i have the following my INI file:

```
    [Meta Tags]
    meta[site_description] = ""
    meta[site_keyword] = ""
    meta[site_title] = "FooBar"
    meta[site_type] = "Website"
    meta[site_url] = "site.com"
    meta[site_image] = ""
```

And If I run the following:

```
$lite = new Config_Lite("myfile", LOCK_EX);
$lite->set("MetaTags", "meta[site_keyword]", "keyword");
$lite->save();
```

I end up with the following in my INI file:

```
    [Meta Tags]
    meta[site_description] = ""
    meta[site_keyword] = ""
    meta[site_title] = "FooBar"
    meta[site_type] = "Website"
    meta[site_url] = "site.com"
    meta[site_image] = "" 
    meta[site_keyword] = "keyword"
```

It doesnt seem to recognise that there is already a value called meta[site_keyword], and just creates a new entry.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're doing anything wrong as such...
This is how I used Config_Lite to update that one specific line:

```
<?php
require_once 'Config/Lite.php';
$lite = new Config_Lite("myfile", LOCK_EX);
$meta = ($lite->get('Meta Tags', 'meta'));
$meta['site_keyword'] = "keyword";
$lite->setSection("Meta Tags", ['meta' => $meta]);
$lite->save();
```

Comment: Hmm! Maybe my syntax was wrong, I'll give that a go, thanks!